# Auto Increment(+) and Decrement(-) button like time picker

Tags: android, increment, decrement, custom-datetimepicker

Hello I'm trying to get an edit increment decrement, to no avail.
I see on Time/Date palette: Time picker, but i want only one box.

I'd like an edit like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ6EI.png]

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can use NumberPicker class. But it is available from SDK v-11. To use in projects that are aimed at SDK versions less 11, you should implement your own class. But you can use AOSP's NumberPicker class as template. Also, but I'm not sure (because I've never tried it) you can use SupportPackage.